# returning two arrays from the same method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return

I'm trying to make a program that will read the high temperatures for 5 days in city A and city B. I've got to make a method for the cities that will take in all 10 values and return them to the main method. I originally had a single method that would count [0]-[4] as cityA and [5]-[9] as cityB, but my professor said that isn't what he wants (even though the answer is technically right).

It's hard to read his handwriting but this seems to be what he was saying to do.

EDIT- I turned it into a variable-length parameter as per suggestions. still working on getting the return statement right but other than that it looks how I would think it should.

EDIT#2 - i just realized that string cities was named city in the main method. fixed that but now i'm getting another error. Return value missing? I'm doing pretty much what the book says now - example in book...

```
printMax(new double[] {1, 2, 3});
if (numbers.length == 0) {
System.out.println("No argument passed");
return;
```

__*_*__*_*__ lastest code

```
public static double[] getHighTemperatures(String cityName, int numberOfDays) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double[] highsForNewYork = getHighTemperatures("New York", 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDays; i++)
    highsForNewYork[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
    return(highsForNewYork);
}
```

__*_*__*_*__ new code

```
package program10a;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class compareCities {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] temp = new double[5];
        String[] cities = new String[]{"Miami", "Dallas";
        getCityTemp(temp, cities);
    }

    public static double[] getCityTemp(double[] temp, String... cities) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (cities.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("No argument passed.");
            return;
        }
        String cityA = cities[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter 5 temperatures for City A. ");
            temp[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
            if (i < cities.length) {
                cityA = cities[i];
            }
        }

        String cityB = cities[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter 5 temperatures for City B. ");
            temp[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
            if (i < cities.length) {
                cityB = cities[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

__*_*__*_*__ below is old code

```
public static double[] getCityHighA(double[] cityA) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < cityA.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter 5 temperatures for City A. ");
        cityA[0] = keyboard.nextDouble();
        cityA[1] = keyboard.nextDouble();
        cityA[2] = keyboard.nextDouble();
        cityA[3] = keyboard.nextDouble();
        cityA[4] = keyboard.nextDouble();
        break;
    }
    return cityA;
}

public static double[] getCityHighB(double[] cityB) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < cityB.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter 5 temperatures for City B. ");
        cityB[0] = keyboard.nextDouble();
        cityB[1] = keyboard.nextDouble();
        cityB[2] = keyboard.nextDouble();
        cityB[3] = keyboard.nextDouble();
        cityB[4] = keyboard.nextDouble();
        break;
    }
    return cityB;
}
```

Is this the most sensible option, or is it possible to use the same method to pass both cityA and cityB back to the main method? Please note that I have not gotten to Objects yet (I've seen similar topics where Object is used and I do not understand how to go about that). Thanks!

Comment: Is this java?  Please specify the programming language in a tag.

Comment: I think that your processor meant that you need to create **one** method which can be reused multiple times (in this case, two times). See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is pretty ugly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cityA.length; i++) {
   System.out.print("Enter 5 temperatures for City A. ");
   cityA[0] = keyboard.nextDouble();
   cityA[1] = keyboard.nextDouble();
   /* ... */
   break;
```

Either use the loop (hint: move the `for` line down a bit and then make the `cityA[]` assignments more generic) or *don't* use the loop and keep the hardcoded array references. (I prefer the `for` loop.)

There are very few cases where putting a `break` statement into the body of a `for` loop makes sense. It certainly shouldn't be used here. (You might never see a reasonable case while you're in school.)

Now, onto the *meat* of your question: returning two arrays from a single function.

I *think* what the professor is suggesting that you should modify the two methods you have here, into a *single* method that you *call twice*. Make your function generic enough to handle the arrays of both cities. (This should not be hard. Locate what is *actually* different between the functions and figure out how to pass the different data in a parameter.)

Your professor might also have wanted you to return a multidimensional array:

```
/* pseudo-code! */
city[][];
city[0][0] = 1; city[0][1] = 2; /* ... */
city[1][0] = 10; city[1][1] = 5; /* ... */
```

But this seems unlikely at this point. (It also doesn't seem worth it for only two cities. Think about this when you need to handle three or more cities.)

**Update**

Your new code is looking significantly better; you're nearly there.

```
public static double[] getHighTemperatures(String cityName, int numberOfDays)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double[] highsForNewYork = getHighTemperatures("New York", 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDays; i++)
        highsForNewYork[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
    return (highsForNewYork);
}
```

`getHighTemperatures()` is calling itself recursively here. While
recursive functions are a very useful technique, it doesn't really help
here. You're calling what is essentially a "helper routine" that could be
used to retrieve data about any city, and have hard coded the cities
you're interested in *within the routine*. Close. :)

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    double[] temp = new double[5];
    String[]cities = new String[] {
        "Miami", "Dallas";
        getCityTemp(temp, cities);
    }
}
```

`main()` has the list of cities, yay, but your array initialization is a
little off. Also, I'd like to suggest that your `getCityTemp()` function
is trying to do too much -- your `main()` should describe, at a very high
level, what you're trying to accomplish with the program as a whole. (The
`main()` function should almost read like an outline.)

```
public static double[] getCityTemp(double[]temp, String ... cities)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (cities.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("No argument passed.");
        return;
    }
    String cityA = cities[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter 5 temperatures for City A. ");
        temp[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
        if (i < cities.length) {
            cityA = cities[i];
        }
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

I generally like this kind of defensive programming -- to see that
*something* has been passed in before relying on it -- but sometimes a
simple `Exception` when things blow up is just fine. It's a nuanced
position between how much "internal APIs" should protect themselves and
what kind of error return values make sense from "external APIs". (These
terms are grand and pompous when applied to a program that very nearly
fits on one screen -- but keep this in mind as you see and build larger
programs.)

But note that you've got keyboard input in *this* function too. (This
might just be a function of iterative development and me coming back to
the question quite late.) It would be *best* to confine all keyboard input
and display output into a small set of functions and do the *computing* (I
assume you'll need to sort the arrays in the next iteration of your
program, so you can find the minimum, maximum, median, average, standard
deviation, etc.) in another set of routines. Try to keep each function
doing as little as possible: make sure each function does *one* thing.

Here's a suggested re-write:

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    String[] cities = {
        "Miami", "Dallas"
    };

    for (String city : cities) {
        double[] highs = getCityTemp(city, 5);
        printCityTemp(city, highs);
    }
}
```

I'm using a [newer style of `for`
loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)
that avoids all the `int i=0; i<array.length; i++` boilerplate code that
is common to a lot of `for` loops. (A great many `for` loops iterate over
all elements of an array.)

```
public static double[] getCityTemp(String city, int days)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double[] highs = new double[days];

    System.out.print("Enter " + days + " temperatures for " + city + ": ");

    for (int i = 0; i < days; i++) {
        highs[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
    }

    return highs;
}
```

All the input is confined to `getCityTemp()`, which is called multiple
times with different parameters to select which city will be displayed.

```
public static void printCityTemp(String city, double[] highs)
{
    System.out.print("Highs for " + city + " were: ");

    for (double high : highs) {
        System.out.print(high + " ");
    }

    System.out.println("");
    return;
}
```

This simple output routine is there to make sure the input was properly
performed. I don't know if it is ideal for your application, but it ought
to be useful when debugging.

Note that I haven't tested this -- it may or may not compile. Probably not. Consider it more *pseudocode* than actual code.

Comment: Yes, he said I am not supposed to use a multidimensional array. So I'm supposed to parameterize it? And I did try the more generic i statement before I just didn't seem to code it right and get any meaningful results. I'll report back with new code

Comment: hi, i edited it into a variable length array (at least how i understand how to make it). can you take a look and tell me how it looks generally? the thing is the return statement doesn't work so it won't compile =(

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to get 2 arrays returned from one method, consider how you can use the same method twice.

Perhaps make it parameterized, a la

```
public double[] getHighTemperatures(String cityName, int numberOfDays)
```

So instead of a having a method hardcoded for city A and another hardcoded for city B, and instead of it being hardcoded to fill in a 5 element array, you can pass any number of cities, any number of days. You simply capture the results each time.

```
double[] highsForNewYork = ...
double[] highsForLosAngeles = ...
```

Comment: @sarnold, didn't feel like accruing points for a non-specific answer on a homework question.

Comment: Hi Anthony, can you look at my code and tell me what's going on with the return statement if you've got a second? I think I passed the variable-length parameter correctly otherwise..

Comment: @user1082706, your new code isn't what I would be looking for, not sure what your professor might want, but it's also not logically correct. Your code is also still doubling the effort. Step back, write the method to perform *one* task, with that task being getting the temperatures for *one* city. Getting two cities' data means you call the method twice. Let the method be dynamic to where, at minimum, you provide the name of the city and perhaps (as in my example) also the number of days you want.

Comment: In my hypothetical version, you do not pass the array *into* the method, you create the array *in* the method and return it to the caller. See my declarations for `highsForNewYork`. The full line of code might be `double[] highsForNewYork = getHighTemperatures("New York", 5);` Where I tell the method the city name is New York and the number of temperatures (or the length of the array) I want is 5. Do you think you might be able to write a method to return that?

Comment: Yes, I'm definitely trying. I just haven't slept in the last day so my head is a bit foggy. I'm trying to get this assignment done by midnight then I can go to bed and come back a little clearer. This is also my second day working with arrays. Sorry I'm not picking it up faster.

Comment: @user1082706, That's good, just remember to not repeat yourself in implementation. Don't write two pieces of code that do the same thing, figure out how to make it reusable. Consider if your professor came back and said "now make it support 5 cities," would you copy and paste the code 3 more times and then sort out how to deal with the results? You could certainly do that, but then the professor might also say, "let *me* decide how many cities I want to support," and you can't possibly know up front how many times to copy the code!

Comment: Or also consider if you make a mistake in the algorithm. How many different places do you have to fix it? So, yes, take a step back, get it working for *one* city, and where the city (inside the method) is not hard coded but rather variable. Then you can call that method as many times as you need to, for as many different cities as you desire.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm trying to get one city working right now

Comment: posted. i tried to use your variables and follow your instructions. if i messed it up this time i think i'll be better off getting some rest and tackling it tomorrow. it's been 36 hours =/

Comment: @user1082706 - Get some rest. You've got some unwanted [recursion](http://www.google.com/search?q=recursion) going on inside the method. Hint: `highsForNewYork` shouldn't be mentioned inside the `getHighTemperatures` method, that is on the outside, it stores the *results* of the method. Although I think you're starting to get close.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I hope we can pick this up where we left off tomorrow!

Answer (score 3):

You could make a two dimensional array:

```
public static double[][] getCityHighs(...) {
    double[] cityA = new double[5];
    //....
    double[] cityB = new double[5];
    //....
    return new double[][]{cityA, cityB};
}
```

double[0] will equal cityA and double[1] will equal cityB. So if you want to get the first value of cityA, then you would do array[0][0];

Or you could create a class that stores the two cities:

```
class cities {
    double[] cityA;
    double[] cityB;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loops are pretty loopy. :)

`i` variable is there for a reason. Instead of what you're doing now, do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cityB.length; ++i) {
    System.out.printf("Enter temperature #%d for City B: ", (i + 1));  // I _think_ there's printf() in Java and it works like C's...
    cityB[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();  // note the use of `i`
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a two dimensional array where the first dimension is the `city`, and the second dimension is the `temperature`. Like this:

```
public static double[][] getHighs() {
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  double[][] temps = new double[2][5];

  for(int i = 0; i < temps.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < temps[i].length; i++) {
      System.out.println("Enter city "+i+"'s temperature #"+j);
      temps[i][j] = keyboard.nextDouble();
    }
  }

  return temps;
}
```

Otherwise, you can parameterize the method as @AnthonyPegram said.